# JavaScript ignores bool

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to do something like a status-check to enable/ disable settings.

```
    // file 1
    function settings( valStatus ){
        var status = valStatus;

        this.getStatus = function(){
            return status;
        }

        this.setStatus = function( valStatus ){
            status = valStatus;
        }
    }
```

calling this function here:

```
    // file 2
    $settings = new settings( false );

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( '#openSettings' ).on('click', function() {
            $settings.setStatus( true );
            enableSettings();
        });

        $('#save').on('click', function(){
            $settings.setStatus( false );
            closeSettings();
        });
    });

    // file 1
    enableSettings = function() {

        if( $settings.getStatus() === true ){

            //toggle emptyLink
            $('.myButton').on('click', function(){
                alert($settings.getStatus());
            });

        }
    }
```

So as startup while clicking on "myButton" nothing happens.
After Clicking on "openSettings" and then on "myButton" i get the alert "true";
After clicking on "save" and then on "myButton" again, i get the alert "false", but it does not even trigger, because i checked it befere.... can somebody help me please?
Where is my mistake?

Comment: You didn't define the `closeSettings()` function anywhere, for one thing...

Comment: Can you post some HTML too, and make a jsfiddle to make the picture complete?

Comment: Every time you `enableSettings()`, you're installing a new alert-handler?

Comment: *"[...] i get the alert "false", but it does not even trigger, because i checked it befere"* What does that mean? What is actually your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to put the check for status inside the `.myButton` click handler instead of outside.  That way you only need to apply the handler once and it will either work or not depending on the value of `status`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $settings = new settings( false );  // keep out of global scope

    $( '#openSettings' ).on('click', function() {
        $settings.setStatus( true );
    });

    $('#save').on('click', function(){
        $settings.setStatus( false );
    });

    $('.myButton').on('click', function(){
        if ($settings.getStatus()) {
            alert($settings.getStatus());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can write JavaScript with less code than e.g. Java. You don't need the getter and setter methods since there is no package visibility. Since you do nothing with the setters you can access your fields directly. This is less code to read and less code where you can have errors. So get rid of useless code (remember this is not the request do code one-liners). Search the internet for "clean code".

Since you are in JavaScript you can do better than that. A smaller approach to store your information.

```
var mySetting = {};
mySetting.status = true

console.log( mySetting.status );
mySetting.status = false;
console.log( mySetting.status );
```

Remember to keep your global space clean! Search the internet for "javascript global scope pollution". So do this within your scope.

Your main problem is, that you are using closures. You probably don't want to use it in your case. Search the internet for "javascript closure tutorial". There are a lot of good ones out there.

Since you are using the Jquery, you can use the .data() function to store your information.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

```
$(function(){
    $( '#openSettings' ).on('click', function() {
        $('#settings').data( "status", true );
        enableSettings();
    });

    $('#save').on('click', function(){
        $('#settings').data( "status", false );
        closeSettings();
    });

    $('.myButton').on('click', function(){
        alert($('#settings').data());
    });
});
```

Or within the HTML itself. See http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$('#settings').attr( "status", true );
console.log( $('#settings').attr( "status" ) );
```

Or as switches.

```
$('#settings').addClass( "settingsEnabled" ); 
$('#settings').removeClass( "settingsEnabled" ); 
console.log($('#settings').hasClass('settingsEnabled'));
```

Use .data() if you want to store object references and HTML for simple information like switches etc. The benefit is, that you can reach that information even with CSS.

And please get rid of the $ prefix in your own code since it has no meaning. If you use frameworks like angular it will help you to identify the origin or like the $$ the ("don't") use of it.